# Why can't cover the test case for the lambda function?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Here is my function for which I wrote a mockito test case which returns the list of github repositores matching a given topic using: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.mylyn.github/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/2.1.5/index.html

githubService is an object of the class GithubService that contains the method getReposByTopics.

```
public CompletionStage<Result> getReposByTopics(String topic_name) {
        CompletionStage<Result> results = cache
                .getOrElseUpdate((topic_name + ".getReposByTopics"),
                        () -> githubService.getReposByTopics(topic_name)
                                .thenApplyAsync(repository -> ok(views.html.topics.render(repository))));
        return results;

    }
```

The Test case is:

```
 @Test
    public void getReposByTopicsTest()
    {
        running(provideApplication(), () -> {
            when(cache.getOrElseUpdate(any(),any())).thenReturn(searchedRepositoriesObject());
            CompletionStage<Result> repositories = githubController.getReposByTopics("mocktopic");
            assertTrue(repositories.toCompletableFuture().isDone());
        });

    }

    /**
     *
     *  mock object for testing getReposByTopicsTest
     * @author Trusha Patel
     * @return CompletionStage<Object> represents the async response containing the process stage of SearchedRepository
     */
    private CompletionStage<Object> searchedRepositoriesObject(){
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            SearchedRepositoryDetails searchedRepositoryDetails = new SearchedRepositoryDetails();
            List<SearchRepository> searchItem = new ArrayList<>();
            SearchRepository searchMock1 = mock(SearchRepository.class);
            when(searchMock1.getOwner()).thenReturn("user1");
            when(searchMock1.getName()).thenReturn("repo1");
            SearchRepository searchMock2 = mock(SearchRepository.class);
            when(searchMock2.getOwner()).thenReturn("user2");
            when(searchMock2.getName()).thenReturn("repo2");
            searchItem.add(searchMock1);
            searchItem.add(searchMock2);
            searchedRepositoryDetails.setRepos(searchItem);
            return searchedRepositoryDetails;
        });
    }

}
```

My jacoco test coverage never covers the lambda..
[image]

The same happens with the other function where instead of mocking the cache, i mock the function:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> getRepositoryDetails(String userName, String repositoryName) {

        CompletionStage<Result> results = cache
                .getOrElseUpdate((userName +"."+repositoryName),
                        () -> githubService.getRepositoryDetails(userName, repositoryName)
                .thenApplyAsync(repository -> ok(views.html.repository.render(repository))));
        return results;
    }
```

Test case:

```
public void getRepositoryDetailsTest()
    {
        running(provideApplication(), () -> {
            when(githubService.getRepositoryDetails(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(repositoryDetails());
            
            CompletionStage<Result> repositoryDetails = githubController.getRepositoryDetails("play", "play");
            try {
                Result result = repositoryDetails.toCompletableFuture().get();
                assertEquals(HttpStatus.SC_OK,result.status());
                assertTrue(contentAsString(result).contains("MockRepoName"));
                assertEquals("text/html",result.contentType().get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    

    private CompletionStage<RepositoryDetails> repositoryDetails(){
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
            RepositoryDetails repositoryDetails = new RepositoryDetails();
            Repository repository = new Repository();
            repository.setName("MockRepoName");
            repositoryDetails.setRepository(repository);
            return repositoryDetails;
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is not surprising - you tell mockito "when `cache.getOrElseUpdate()` is called with two parameters (no matter what that parameters are) then ignore the parameters and return the result of `searchedRepositoriesObject()`"

Comment: Even when I mock the function geithubserviceMock.getReposByTopics,I cannot cover the lambda!